# How did Lagrange derive this Hamilton-like equation in Mechanique analytique

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, history

I was trying to understand how Hamiltonian formulation was derived in the history, and read Mechanicque Analytique, and found these pages from section V of this book, which derived the Hamiltonian-like equation
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{\mathrm{d} \Omega}{\mathrm{d} \alpha} \mathrm{d} t=\delta \lambda, & \frac{\mathrm{d} \Omega}{\mathrm{d} \beta} \mathrm{d} t=\delta \mu, & \frac{\mathrm{d} \Omega}{\mathrm{d} \gamma} \mathrm{d} t=\delta \nu \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} \Omega}{\mathrm{d} \lambda} \mathrm{d} t=-\delta \alpha, & \frac{\mathrm{d} \Omega}{\mathrm{d} \mu} \mathrm{d} t=-\delta \beta, & \frac{\mathrm{d} \Omega}{\mathrm{d} \nu} \mathrm{d} t=-\delta \gamma
\end{array}
$$
in the last stage. I think this is the first motivation of Hamilton mechanics, and really wanted to understand what these pages are deriving, but I found I cannot understand them since in Lagrange's era the symbols used for calculus are very different from the ones we use nowadays.

My question is: **what these pages are deriving, and what does this Hamiltonian-like equation tells us?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.